# Translation of "Anmk."

Tags: translation, german-to-english, abbreviation

In several German papers I've found such abbreviation as "10 Anmk. 1", but I have no idea how this could be translated. This looks like some abbreviation of well known edition. Contexts are:

1) "In meinem ... veroffentlichten Buche *Blabla* hatte ich **10 Anmk. 1** (der vorigen Seite!) Gelegenheit,..."

2) "... though under the head of temporal uses (p. 217, **10, Anmk. 1**) this remark is made..."

3) "Vgl. Winer Gr. 46. **10. Anmk. 1.** und unsern..."

4) "S. Bottger Beitr. IV, 23. **Anmk**."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Anmk.* or *Anm* is an abbreviation for *Anmerkung*, which in this context should be an explanatory note / remark / note.

**10 Anm. 1** means Remark Nr. 10 Paragraph 1

Answer (score 5):

*Anmk.* is *Anmerkung* (remark), also abbreviated *Anm.*

Then, for instance

> 23. Anmk.

is the 23rd remark.

---

As side note: *Anmk.* seems to be replaced by *Anm.*, as this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Anmk.&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAnmk%20.%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CAnmk%20.%3B%2Cc0-1) suggests.